# PostgreSQLCopyHelper Bulk Insert Postgresql Table C# Fixed Width File

Tags: c#, postgresql, import, bulkinsert, fixed-width

I am attempting to Bukl Insert data from Fixed Width File into a Postgresql Table. I came accross the library PostgreSQLCopyHelper

https://github.com/bytefish/PostgreSQLCopyHelper

This is my update action in controller *(updated 15/06/17)*

```
        ProductData  pd = new ProductData();

        public ActionResult Update(q_product q_product, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
        {
        ProductData pd;
        var entities = new List<ProductData>();
        PostgreSQLCopyHelper<ProductData> insert;                       

        try
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid && upload != null)
            {                    
                //uploaded file
                Stream stream = upload.InputStream;

                //need to use BULK INSERT or MULTIPLE INSERT at this point;                    

                //get the properties (columns) as set in ProductData.cs
                using (var fdr = new FileDataReader<ProductData>(stream))
                {
                    //read and get each line on imported file
                    while ((pd = fdr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        //Lets populate insert
                        //map table columns with properties
                        insert = new PostgreSQLCopyHelper<ProductData>("public", "q_product")
                            .MapUUID("q_guid", x => Guid.NewGuid())
                            .MapText("q_barcode", x => pd.barcode)
                            .MapText("q_description", x => pd.description)
                            .MapText("q_import_size", x => pd.size)
                            .MapNumeric("q_stocklevel", x => pd.quantity)
                            .MapText("q_import_vatcode", x => pd.vatCode) //vatcode is numeric in DB, this is a String (new column for this test)
                            .MapNumeric("q_casecost", x => pd.cost)
                            .MapNumeric("q_sellprice", x => pd.price);                            

                        //add the populated entries as we iterate through the file
                        entities.Add(pd);

                        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=192.168.0.52;Database=bolo;Username=western;Password=western"))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                connection.Open();
                                insert.SaveAll(connection, entities);                                    
                                int lineCount = entities.Count();
                                TempData["SuccessMessage"] = lineCount+" Records Inserted!";
                            }
                            catch (Exception er)
                            {                                    
                                TempData["ErrorMessage"] = er.Message;
                                //TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Error: importing records!";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        catch(DataException error)
        {
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Error importing records!";
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Message);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

ProductData.cs file

```
public class ProductData 
{
    [Layout(22, 13)]
    public string barcode;        

    [Layout(49, 25)]
    public string description;

    [Layout(74, 5)]
    public string size;

    [Layout(95, 4)]
    public int quantity;

    [Layout(99, 1)]
    public string vatCode;

    [Layout(108, 7)]
    public decimal cost;

    [Layout(115, 7)]
    public decimal price;

    public override string ToString()
    {            
        return String.Format("string: {0}; string: {1}; string: {2}; int: {3}; string: {4}; decimal {5}; decimal {6}",
                barcode, description, size, quantity, vatCode, cost, price
            );            
    }
}
```

Upon debugging, the

> entities

parameter on this line in the update action

```
 insert.SaveAll(connection, entities);
```

happens to be null, thus no row is getting saved  and its throwing an "Object not set reference" error. Now from the limited documentation about this CopyHelper library I cannot figure out which class or paramater I have to make IEnumerable, as SaveAll requries an IEnumerable second parameter

[image: Debug Screen]

As you can see from the debug screen, my pd (ProductData) has the values it needs to store in the table. How do I link that with the IEnumerable paramater needed in the SaveAll method?

[image: Cant close writer, a row is still in progress, end it first]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want something like:

```
public ActionResult Update(q_product q_product, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{    
    ProductData pd;
    var entities = new List<ProductData>();
    PostgreSQLCopyHelper<ProductData> insert = null;
    try
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid && upload != null)
        {                    
            //uploaded file
            Stream stream = upload.InputStream;

            //need to use BULK INSERT or MULTIPLE INSERT at this point;                    

            //get the properties (columns)
            using (var fdr = new FileDataReader<ProductData>(stream))
            {
                //get each line on file
                while ((pd = fdr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //map table columns with properties
                    insert = insert ?? new PostgreSQLCopyHelper<ProductData>("public","q_product")
                        .MapUUID("q_guid", x => Guid.NewGuid())
                        .MapText("q_barcode", x => this.pd.barcode)
                        .MapText("q_description", x => this.pd.description)
                        .MapText("q_size", x => pd.size) 
                        .MapInteger("q_stocklevel", x => this.pd.quantity)
                        .MapText("q_vatcode", x => pd.vatCode)  
                        .MapMoney("q_casecost", x => this.pd.cost)
                        .MapMoney("q_sellprice", x => this.pd.price);
                    entities.Add(pd);
                }
            }
            using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=192.168.0.52;Database=tester;Username=test;Password=test"))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    insert.SaveAll(connection, entities);                                    
                    TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Records Inserted!";
                }
                catch (Exception er)
                {
                    TempData["ErrorMessage"] = er.Message;                                    
                    //TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Error importing records!";
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }

    catch(DataException error)
    {
        TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Error importing records!";
        ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Message);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The key change is populating `insert` only once, and then adding entries to `entities` as you iterate through the uploaded files.

Comment: Thanks for the assist @mjwills. This nudged me in the right direction. Only issue though is somehow its only adding the first line into the table. And whats happening on this code
`insert = insert ?? ` coz thats giving me an error "use of unassigned local variable" even when I have this line further up
`PostgreSQLCopyHelper<ProductData> insert;`

Comment: I solved that one row only insertion issue with this line (an oversight on my end) `.MapUUID("q_guid", x => Guid.NewGuid())`. All records are getting inserted but now the issue is: I tested with a file that only has 3 rows (records) to start small.
line 1: is inserted once
line 2: is inserted twice (two records in table)
line 3: is inserted thrice (three records in table) an so on
I have updated the update action to show you what I am working with.

Comment: I have changed it like you have in your code, and I get an error on the line 
`insert = insert ??`
I updated post with image on the code and error

Comment: added that, and now on import I get the following error
`Can't close writer, a row is still in progress, end it first`

Comment: at this line `insert.SaveAll(connection, entities);`
I assume one has to manually dispose connection? I am probably wrong

Comment: Yes I am sure, when using the code with the duplication issue.. the records are inserted fine and into the proper table and appropriate columns. Just line 2 and 3 are getting inserted twice. So I dont think theres an issue with schema, table and columns. I was already on those two links you sent, couldnt find a solution.

Comment: Alas, I think you will need to raise an issue with the people who built the libraries you are using. :(

Comment: solved the issue. It was actually an oversight on my hand. On mapping my properties I had 
`.MapText("q_barcode", x => pd.barcode)` instead of
`.MapText("q_barcode", x => x.barcode)`. 
Its something I had changed before while debugging, and completely forgot about. Thanks for your patience and assistance @mjwillis. You helped me with the original issue of `entities` being null and then some. Much appreciated.

Comment: Ah, apologies that I failed to notice that. And great job getting it working!

Answer (score 1):

adding on to the awesome and much appreciated answer by mjwillis, if one cannot see the comment section. The following code put everything in order:
change the mapping from

```
.MapText("q_barcode", x => this.pd.barcode)
```

to

```
.MapVarchar("q_barcode", x => x.barcode)
```

as follows

```
//map table columns with properties
                        insert = insert ?? new PostgreSQLCopyHelper<ProductData>("public", "q_product")
                            .MapUUID("q_guid", x => Guid.NewGuid())
                            .MapVarchar("q_barcode", x => x.barcode)
                            .MapVarchar("q_description", x => x.description)
                            .MapVarchar("q_import_size", x => x.size)
                            .MapNumeric("q_stocklevel", x => x.quantity)
                            .MapVarchar("q_import_vatcode", x => x.vatCode) 
                            .MapNumeric("q_casecost", x => x.cost)
                            .MapNumeric("q_sellprice", x => x.price);
```