# XML Bulk Import of Records Using PostgreSQLCopyHelper - Npgsql.PostgresException: 42601

Tags: xml, postgresql, import

On importing records from an XML with two records file into database table, I have an issue were the first record is being inserted twice while the second record isn't getting saved into the table.

This is the XML file with the two records/products

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ProdExtract>

 <ExtractHeader>
  <Schema>
   <id>Accord ePOS Product Extract</id>
   <Version>1.00</Version>
  </Schema>  
 </ExtractHeader>

 <Product>
  <Mode>Modify</Mode>
   <ProductID>  
    <LongDescription>ZOLMANS MINT SAUCE      #</LongDescription>  
   </ProductID>
   <BasicFields>  
    <Units>6</Units>
    <VAT VatCode="A" VatRate="0" />  
   </BasicFields>
   <Price>  
    <CurrentWSP>9.55</CurrentWSP>
    <CurrentRSP>2.01</CurrentRSP>  
   </Price>
   <Barcode>  
    <Eancode>5000147032921</Eancode>  
   </Barcode>
 </Product>

 <Product>
  <Mode>Modify</Mode>
   <ProductID>  
    <LongDescription>TEST XML IMPORT PRODUCT     </LongDescription>  
   </ProductID>
   <BasicFields>  
    <Units>10</Units>
    <VAT VatCode="A" VatRate="0" />  
   </BasicFields>
   <Price>  
    <CurrentWSP>8.88</CurrentWSP>
    <CurrentRSP>2.22</CurrentRSP>  
   </Price>
   <Barcode>  
    <Eancode>5000147032923</Eancode>  
   </Barcode>
 </Product>

</ProdExtract>
```

Reading the file and saving it to the database table

```
var entities = new List<ProductViewModel>();
        PostgreSQLCopyHelper<ProductViewModel> insert = null;

        NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=192.168.0.52;Database=bolo;Username=western;Password=western");
        connection.Open(); /*OPEN DATABASE CONNECTION*/            

        ProductViewModel p;            

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && upload != null)
            {
                //uploaded file
                Stream stream = upload.InputStream;

                XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xDoc.Load(stream);
                XmlElement root = xDoc.DocumentElement;
                XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("Product");

                foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)                    
                {
                    //while((p = node.InnerText) != null)
                    {
                        insert = new PostgreSQLCopyHelper<ProductViewModel>("public", "q_product");
                        p = new ProductViewModel();
                        p.q_guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                        p.q_description = node.SelectSingleNode("ProductID/LongDescription").InnerText;
                        p.q_barcode = node.SelectSingleNode("Barcode / Eancode").InnerText;
                        p.q_casesize = Convert.ToDecimal(node.SelectSingleNode("BasicFields/Units").InnerText);
                        p.q_sellprice = Convert.ToDecimal(node.SelectSingleNode("Price/CurrentRSP").InnerText);
                        p.q_casecost = Convert.ToDecimal(node.SelectSingleNode("Price/CurrentWSP").InnerText);
                        entities.Add(p);
                    }                        
                }

                try
                {
                   insert.SaveAll(connection, entities);
                    int lineCount = entities.Count();
                    TempData["SuccessMessage"] = lineCount + " Records Inserted!";
                    connection.Close(); /*CLOSE CONNECTION*/
                }
                catch (DataException error)
                {
                    TempData["ErrorMessage"] = error.Message;
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }                
        }
        catch(DataException error)
        {

            ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Message);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

**UPDATE**

Mapping this way, only gets the first row saved into the table. Testing with a file that only has 3 products, and the first row will get saved 3 times in the table.

```
insert = insert ?? new PostgreSQLCopyHelper<ProductViewModel>("public", "q_product")
   .MapUUID("q_guid", x => Guid.NewGuid())
   .MapText("q_description", x => node.SelectSingleNode("ProductID/LongDescription").InnerText)
   .MapText("q_barcode", x => node.SelectSingleNode("Barcode/Eancode").InnerText)
  etc........
                        ;
  entities.Add(p);
```

Mapping this way gets all the approppiate records into `entities.Add(p)` but is crashing out on the line `insert.SaveAll(connection, entities);` with error `Npgsql.PostgresException: 42601: syntax error at or near ")"`... because insert has no columns to insert data into at time of saving.

```
insert = new PostgreSQLCopyHelper<ProductViewModel>("public", "q_product");
      p = new ProductViewModel();
      p.q_guid = Guid.NewGuid();
      p.q_description = node.SelectSingleNode("ProductID/LongDescription").InnerText;
      p.q_barcode = node.SelectSingleNode("Barcode / Eancode").InnerText;
      p.q_casesize = Convert.ToDecimal(node.SelectSingleNode("BasicFields/Units").InnerText);
      p.q_sellprice = Convert.ToDecimal(node.SelectSingleNode("Price/CurrentRSP").InnerText);
      p.q_casecost = Convert.ToDecimal(node.SelectSingleNode("Price/CurrentWSP").InnerText);
      entities.Add(p);
```

**Update Solution**

Removing the line
`insert = new PostgreSQLCopyHelper<ProductViewModel>("public", "q_product");`

and using the following, works for my current needs. I am aware there are probably faster methods than this solution, but this works for my current needs at the moment.

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand
                            ("INSERT INTO q_product (q_guid, q_description, q_barcode, q_casesize, q_sellprice, q_casecost, q_import_vatcode)" +
                            "VALUES (@pk, @des, @bcode, @csize, @sprice, @ccost, @vcode )",
                            con);

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk", p.q_guid);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@des", p.q_description);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bcode", p.q_barcode);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@csize", p.q_casesize);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sprice", p.q_sellprice);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccost", p.q_casecost);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vcode", p.q_import_vatcode);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What are the column names in `q_product`? I also suspect you need some mapping code - similar to what you have over in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44722465/34092 .

Comment: my columns in q_product are q_guid, q_description, q_barcode etc. I was using the mapping code similar to that link before when I had the issue of populating p.

Comment: @mjwills I updated post (bottom) with the issue I am getting on either types of mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are repeatedly adding the same element:

```
entities.Add(p);
```

On each iteration of the loop you need to create a new object and set properties on it:

```
p = new WhateverYourTypeIs();
p.Property1 = node.Something;
p.Property2 = node.SomethingElse;
entities.Add(p);
```

etc.

Comment: @mjwillis Your solution worked for me, after I decided to use an insert statement with sqlcommand, rather than bulk insert. It works for my current needs, but will still be researching how to make it work like the previous fised width file solution. Thanks.